# Redirect pages which end in a nubmer

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

This is such a stupid question, I'm so close to solving it but regex is killing me – I'm using the JavaScript history api on various pages of a test.

Server side, I would like to redirect:

```
/test/1
/test/2
/test/3
```

All to

```
/test
```

So I am using

```
Redirect 301 /test/1 /test
Redirect 301 /test/2 /test
Redirect 301 /test/3 /test
```

This all works, but I would like to redirect

```
Redirect 301 /test/1000 /test
```

So, here is where I am going wrong, after some hacking, googling etc I'm using:

```
Redirect 301 /test/([0-9]+) /test
```

to replace all other lines of code, but it's totally failing. What's the line to match all `/test/{number}` so I can redirect them all at once?

Comment: Maybe RedirectMatch instead? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Comment: If you add this as a comment it's all yours! `RedirectMatch 301 /test/[0-9]+ /test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect doesn't support regex, but RedirectMatch does: httpd://apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmat‌​ch

It would read:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /test/[0-9]+ /test
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive doesn't support Regular Expressions. Instead you can try `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^test/[0-9]+$ /test [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this expression will work for you.

`/(?:\d*)?\d+/g`

http://regexr.com/3e8bk